# "Makes you/me/..." by a nonhuman agent

Tags: grammar, causation

I'm wondering how sentences are typically made for the pattern "(some non human thing) makes me/you/etc (reaction)." For example, "reading this book makes me think." Or "going to school makes me happy." I suppose if you directly translated these it would be something using ～させる, like この本読むと考えさせる but I feel like that is usually unnatural in this case. It seems using words like ～たくなる and such are more common. What is the extent of ～させるs usefulness in this case and what is the most natural option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have partly answered your own question. Historically, Japanese has tended not to use an inanimate thing as a subject as if it had its own will. It's usually preferred to rephrase the sentence using a human as the subject. In your examples, you can say:

> - この本を読むと考えさせられる。
>   <sub>(Literally, "When I read this book, I am made to think." Notice the causative-passive form. この本を読むと考えたくなる means "This books make me feel like thinking deeply", and this may be fine if the book is a certain type of self-help book.)</sub>
> - 学校に行くと楽しくなる。
>   <sub>(Lit. "When I go to school, I become happy.")</sub>

The following sentences are not wrong but tend to sound less natural in Japanese:

> - この本は私に考えさせる。
>   <sub>(Lit. "This book makes me think.")</sub>
> - 学校に行くことは私を楽しくさせる。
>   <sub>(Lit. "Going to school makes me happy.")</sub>

See this question for similar examples:  [In Japanese, can we say an object asks a question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32436/5010)

This is also related: [Does 考えさせられる小説 make sense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61710/5010)